# MS Word 2016 - How to set page number from heading to heading

Tags: ms-word, numbers

how to set page number from heading to heading? I have three heading and I want to set page number. Heading one (1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3), Heading two (1 of 2, 2 of 2), Heading three (1 of 10, 2 of 10, etc...)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. This site is dedicated to programming, how is your question related to that? Are you creating a Word document programatically? You might be better of, posting your question on a different site of the StackExchange network, such as SuperUser.com.

Comment: Don't forget to add the word version in your question.

Comment: Oh thanks, i forgot

Comment: Anyone can help me?